# SharePoint Designer Menu for Filtering Joined Views

Tags: sharepoint-designer, data-view-web-part, xslt, data-form-web-part, joined-view

In SharePoint Designer, is there an easy interface for filtering joined views (either parent or child)?

Currently I go to code view to type the filters directly in xslt. There must be an easier way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't anything in the SPD GUI to accomplish this.  You would need to do it like you are doing it in the XSLT.  Other way would be to use a Visual Studio solution, but you would be doing even more code that way.